# How to launch PyCharm's debugger with breakpoint()

Tags: python, pycharm

I understand that I can set which debugger is launched by setting [`sys.breakpointhook()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.breakpointhook), but what do I set it to in order to launch PyCharm's IDE?

To clarify, I want PyCharm's debugger to launch when it encounters the `breakpoint()` builtin, especially if I'm running the program from PyCharm.

If you're wondering "why ever do this when you could just run from the debugger?" I'm trying to debug some code that responds differently when started with the debugger.

Comment: If you run the application from PyCharm, and set the breakpoint from within PyCharm, then it will stop in PyCharm. What's your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ueli's answer got me 99% of the way there. Here's the summary.

If you want the PyCharm debugger to start, [all you need to do is import it](https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/blob/37d804c7ac968694ce29c93392e3bed6fda641f0/pydevd.py#L132). There are a couple ways:

> You can use the `pydevd-pycharm.egg` from the PyCharm installation (`<PyCharm directory>/debug-egg/pydevd-pycharm.egg`) or install the `pydevd-pycharm` package using pip.

If you're running things locally, the simplest would just be to add

```
sys.path.append("<PyCharm directory>/debug-egg/pydevd-pycharm.egg")
import pydevd_pycharm
```

somewhere in the program you are debugging.

If you're Trying to debug on a remote machine, you will need to install `pydevd-pycharm`:

```
pip install pydevd-pycharm~=<version of PyCharm on the local machine>
```

before adding

```
import pydevd_pycharm
```

Somewhere in the program.

The instructions for how to import `pydevd_pycharm` is coppied from step 4 of https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config (as linked in Ueli's answer).

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm uses the pydevd debugger https://pypi.org/project/pydevd-pycharm/. So assuming you want to debug a Python application started outside of PyCharm, you have two options:

- either attach the process, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/attaching-to-local-process.html#attach-to-local or
- start Pycharm as debug server and than connect to it from your application, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html.

The second option is probably closer to what you have in mind, i.e. instead of setting the debugger using `sys.breakpointhook`, you install the debugger using  `pydevd_pycharm.settrace(...)` which then connects to PyCharm (where you can set the breakpoints in the source files).

Installing the custom breakpointhook by pointing sys.breakpointhook to the pydevd breakpointhook (i.e. pointing to the "Pycharm Debugger") will be done by pydevd (https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/blob/37d804c7ac968694ce29c93392e3bed6fda641f0/pydevd.py#L95, line 117 to be precise).

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly helpful, and I can use it to accomplish my goal. Just to clarify, are you saying then that there isn't a way to point `sys.breakpointhook` at the PyCharm debugger?

Comment: sys.breakpointhook will be called by pydevd, I modified the answer accordingly.